# Why JsonConvert is Faster than ASP.NET Core's Built-In Json Formatter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I learned that ASP.NET Core uses Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1 as its built-in JSON formatter ([Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch](https://github.com/aspnet/JsonPatch/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch/project.json#L29)). However, I still have not figured out what causes the performance difference between these two codes:

**Using Built-In JSON Formatter (Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1)**

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/BuiltIn")]
public class BuiltInController : Controller
{
    private static readonly BufferBlock<ParentModel> Block = new BufferBlock<ParentModel>();

    // GET: api/BuiltIn
    [HttpGet]
    public ParentModel Get()
    {
        if (!Block.TryReceive(out ParentModel model)) return null;
        return model;
    }

    // POST: api/BuiltIn
    [HttpPost]
    public bool Post([FromBody]ParentModel model)
    {
        if (model == null) return false;
        return Block.Post(model);
    }
}
```

> Results (10k requests):
>
> POST - 64 minutes 19 seconds, GET - 57 minutes 8 seconds

**Using JsonConvert (Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1 referenced in AspNetCore)**

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/JsonConvert")]
public class JsonConvertController : Controller
{
    private static readonly BufferBlock<ParentModel> Block = new BufferBlock<ParentModel>();

    // GET: api/JsonConvert
    [HttpGet]
    public ContentResult Get()
    {
        if (!Block.TryReceive(out ParentModel model)) return Content(null);
        return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));
    }

    // POST: api/JsonConvert
    [HttpPost]
    public bool Post()
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
        {
            var request = reader.ReadToEnd();
            if (request == null) return false;
            var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParentModel>(request);
            return Block.Post(model);
        }
    }
}
```

> Results (10k requests):
>
> POST - 63 minutes 47 seconds, GET - 56 minutes 18 seconds

No matter how many requests I test, direct use of JsonConvert gives slightly better performance (about 1%). What could be the reason of this performance difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you profile it, we can't tell you.

But you should ignore the little difference, it's most likely due to the additional GCs triggered by the fact that when you use `Content(...)` or `Ok(...)` helper methods, you also always instantiate an `ContentResult` and/or `OkObjectResult` (see [BaseController.cs source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L314-L317)) and when directly returning the model these are probably reused.

```
[NonAction]
public virtual OkObjectResult Ok(object value)
{
    return new OkObjectResult(value);
}
```

Also your tests are most likely wrong, as ASP.NET Core is well capable of doing 200k requests per second (see [TechEmpower Benchmark, Round 14](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r14&hw=ph&test=json)) or you are not utilizing http Pipeline, not running the benchmark tool and ASP.NET Application on different physical computers etc.

#### Update

Also please note, that the second test with `public bool Post()` doesn't invoke the model binder, `public bool Post([FromBody]ParentModel model)` does however. When you have the model as parameter, ASP.NET Core has to invoke `IModelBinderFactory.CreateBinder` ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/IModelBinderFactory.cs#L16)) to obtain the correct model binder (i.e. `ComplexTypeModelBinder` and others depending on how your model looks like, like `ArrayModelBinder`, `DictionaryModelBinder`, `BodyModelBinder`, etc.).

So what your test does is effectively testing performance of model binder and/or overhead (incl. instantiation of `ContentResult`) of the `return Content(string)` methods and **not** JSON.NET direct vs. JSON.NET called by ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I guess your first statement is probably the reason, but I'll dig more from there. I'll also try to find an appropriate way to benchmark. Do you have any suggestion or reference to that?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: What "additional GC" are you talking about exactly? The source you have posted yourself shows that all those helper methods do is instantiate the appropriate result and return it. I expect the overhead of this to be absolutely negligible, possibly zero.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy: Of creating `ContentResult` on each request instances on each request, were there could be an optimization of it being reused when returning `ParentModel`. So it's at least one object more that is guaranteed to be instantiated on every request and this may lead that the GC is triggered more often, maybe even a higher tier GC (Gen1 or Gen2), which requires significantly more time to collect than Gen0. The point in the end is, the code used to perform the test is **not equal**. First test returns a model, second returns a `ContentResult`, so we can't even compare these

Comment: If the op would have used `public ContentResult Get()` and `public bool Post()` and **then** read from the request on both tests, they could be compared. Additionally, the first test with `public bool Post([FromBody]ParentModel model)` will invoke the ModelBinder, were `public bool Post()` won't, because there is no parameters inside the action

Answer (score 0):

The performance of JSON serialization will improve drastically with the release of .NET Core 3.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/

The blog post also includes some metrics that outline the improvements you can expect.